# Python calculations for ATL (and later CTL) with trainingdata

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a calculation in a dataframe for different athletes.
I hava a dataframe with 200 dates (starting always from today till 200 days in the past) for multiple athletes.

Every athlete has the following data:
(The ATL data is desired results (made in excel now :) )

[image]

I tried everything in Python and stack (and even ChatGPT), but can not make it work.
The formula used is:

```
ATLtoday = ATLyesterday + (TSStoday - ATLyesterday)*(1/7)
```

Hopefully somebody can help me calculate these values per athlete for the 200 dates.
Thank you in advance!!